# How do I centralise the instantiation of the classes?

Tags: c#

I am trying to improve some legacy code in asp.net webforms. The following instantiation is being repeated in lots of classes. Is there a way to centralise it?

```
public class Job : WebService {
    private readonly DataHandler _data;
    private SecurityHandler _security;
    private readonly ContentHandler _content;
    private readonly CoreHandler _core;

    public Job()
    {
        _content = new ContentHandler();
        _security = new SecurityHandler();
        _data = new DataHandler();
        _core = new CoreHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are instantiating a `Job` in multiple classes and want to know if you could have one central `Job` that all of those classes could access?

Comment: If so, making `Job` a static class that you can access from multiple places could be a potential solution.

Comment: Job is a constructor in which ContentHandler, SecurityHander, DataHandler and CoreHandler are being instantiated. The handlers are being instantiated in the constructors of many other classes.

Comment: Introduce a common ancestor? `public class BaseService : WebService { protected readonly....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice not to be overly aggressive with code de-duplication. The goal should typically be to avoid duplication of data, or duplication of any complicated logic.

Your example is perfectly readable and easy to understand, so you should be careful when making changes not to make it less easy to understand.

The simplest way would be to just create a `Handler`-class that creates these four classes and exposes them as public properties.

A better alternative in my opinion would be to use a dependency injection framework to inject these classes in the constructor. It does not really make the code shorter, but it lets the DI-framework worry about how the various types depend on each other, and that is typically a larger issue.